# android- How to right to left text on popup menu item

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i've a popup menu in my application :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:title="One"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:title="Two"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:title="Three"/>
```

It's a popup menu , I call it this way :

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(FistActiivty.this, menuinco);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
              Toast.makeText(FistActiivty.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
             }
            });

            popup.show();//showing popup menu
```

it opens a popup mene and it's ok.

The problem is that items are left to right .

How can I make popup menu's text alignment right to left ? 
I want to run my application on api 8+

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not do that in native way, because RTL was started to support at Android 4.2 (see [official blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)).

It's only one possible solution, create custom popup menu or find already implemented 3rd library.

Comment: thanks for reply , Do you know any library to do so ?